# how to remove element from reference array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using before code to get every first id and remove that id but it show error undefine offset.

I don't understand What i missed in the below code ?

```
$products = Array
    (
        [32] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44
                [1] => 45
                [2] => 926
                [3] => 927
                [4] => 930
                [5] => 931
            )

        [41] => Array
            (
                [0] => 928
                [1] => 933
                [2] => 969
                [3] => 970
                [4] => 971
                [5] => 972
                [6] => 973
                [7] => 974
                [8] => 975
                [9] => 976
                [10] => 977
                [11] => 978
                [12] => 979
                [13] => 980
                [14] => 981));

    $in_array = array();

    for($i=0;$i<12;)
    {
        foreach($products as &$brands):                 
            if(isset($brands[0]))
            {
                $id = $brands[0];// get the first element
                unset( $brands[0]); // have remove that element form products
                // But here it show error undefine offset 0

                array_push($in_array,$id);

                /*if(($key1 = array_search($id, $brands)) !== false) {
                     unset($brands[$key1]);
                }*/
                //I tried this too same error

                $i++;
            }           
        endforeach;     

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$brands[0]` doesn't seem to exist(I only see 32 and 41 in your code).

If you'd like to remove the first element in $products[32] than you need another foreach in your foreach:

```
foreach($products as $brands) {
    foreach($brands as $brand) {
        //Here is where you can reach $brand[0](Which is 44 in $products[32])
    }
}
```

If you'd like to remove the first element of the array, you can use [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: I need to remove $products[32][0] element

Comment: @user3449452 So simply use `unset($products[32][0]);` notation

Comment: Use my first foreach and array_shift (`array_shift($brands)`) or as @hindmost says; `unset()` it in a 2nd foreach.

Answer (score 0):

By the help of mr  @CaptainCarl  i change my loop it working fine

```
  for($i=0;$i<12;)
            {
                foreach($products_ids as $key=>$brands):
                    if(isset($brands[0]))
                    {
                        $id = $brands[0];
                        array_push($in_array,$id);
                        array_shift($brands);
                        $i++;   
                    }
                    $products_ids[$key] = $brands;              
                endforeach;         
            }
```